# Concatenating a list of xml strings into a single xml file using Python

Tags: python, xml, dom

I am trying to get several pages of xml using a web service api. I am using urllib2 to read a url and then store the string into a list. I then iterate through the pages of xml until there are no more pages left.

```
    def run(self):
        issuesxml = []
        for rule in self.ruleRepo[1:]:
            pageIndex = 1
            while True:
                url = self.baseURL + '&rules='+str(self.ruleRepo[0])+':'+str(rule) + '&pageIndex='+ str(pageIndex)
                rule_string = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
                dom = parseString(rule_string)

                #if there are issue tags then proceed
                if len(dom.getElementsByTagName('issue')) != 0:
                    issuesxml.append(rule_string)
                    pageIndex += pageIndex
                else:
                    break
```

So `issuesxml` contains a list of strings, each corresponding to a page of xml. I tested this line and it works. I just don't know how to make the list into a single xml file that I can then turn into a csv file for excel. Sorry, if my code is sucks. I started Python about 3 months ago and still need to learn a lot.

Comment: `"\n".join(issuesxml)` to concat them, but why not process them one at a time?

Comment: process into csv file? Wouldn't that take longer?

Comment: If you found an answer that works submit one and then accept it please.

Comment: @Fabricator Can you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `delim.join(list)` to concat a list

```
"\n".join(issuesxml)
```